# How to get a selectedItem and handle a button click event at the same time?

Tags: meteor

Instead of selecting an item first and then using a button to perform some action on the selected item I would prefer for the user to perform one click.

It seems to work but I have concerns that the event on the button must occur after the event on the carpool_event. This just doesn't seem right. Is there a better way to handle this? Thanks!

in my HTML

```
<template name="carpool_list">
  <h1>Carpool</h1>
  {{#each carpool_events}}
  <ul>
    {{> carpool_event}}
  </ul>
  {{else}}
    No events yet.
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="carpool_event">
  <div class="carpool_event">
    <span class="localDate">{{localDate}}</span>
    <span class="owner">{{owner}}</span>
    {{#if currentUser}}
      <span><input type="button" class="takeEvent" value="Take Event"/></span>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

corresponding js

```
Template.carpool_event.events({
    'click': function () {
      Session.set("selected_carpool_event", this._id);
    }
  });

Template.carpool_list.events({
    /**
     * Take Event Handler
     */
    'click .takeEvent': function () {
      console.log("Take event:"+Session.get("selected_carpool_event"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use one click handler?

Comment: Are you using an #each somewhere? Could you detail how you're using it too? You could just use _id in your button click instead of asking for the session.get variable

Comment: If I use just one click handler on the button how can I get the _id? When I look at the target or currentTarget it is just the button. Yes the template carpool_event is in an #each in another template. I will post the code as soon as I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Template.carpool_event.events({
"click": function () {
      Session.set("selected_carpool_event", this._id);
      if($(event.target).attr("class") == "takeEvent" && Meteor.userId) {
         console.log("Take event:"+this._id);
      }
    }
});
```

or if you want both clicks for some other reason or you can avoid having capturing the first click you could target the button directly, `this._id` should work on the button too (you can assign a handler to the same template `carpool_event` for a button anywhere inside the template)

```
Template.carpool_event.events({
    /**
     * Take Event Handler
     */
    "click .takeEvent": function () {
       Session.set("selected_carpool_event", this._id);
       if(Meteor.userId) {
           console.log("Take event:"+this._id);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and report back.